# Sort an arraylist of strings with following conditions?

Tags: java

I have an arraylist of strings in the form of:

> {T1, C1, C2, T2, C3, T3, A1, T4, G1, A2, G2, A3, T5, C4, C5, T6, A4, T7, T8, C6, T9, A5, T10, G3, A6, A7, A8, C7, C8, T11, T12, C9, A9, $1, G4, A10, C10, C11, A11, A12, A13, A14, T13, T14, C12, T15, C13, C14, G5, G6, C15}

I want to sort this arraylist to the following:

> {$1, A1, A2...A10, A11,... C1, C2...C14....}.

however, when I used `Collections.sort()`, the result turns out to be:

> {$1, A1, A10, A11, A12, A13, A14, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9, C1, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9, G1, G2, G3, G4, G5, G6, T1, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9}

with A2 comes after A14. So is there a way to solve this issue? Thanks so much!

Comment: You're getting that result because Collections.sort() in this case is sorting alphabetically, you will have to write a custom Comparator to achieve a different sorting.
Here are some examples: 
https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Comparator.comparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) method chain to define the sort criteria. Define the first comparison as `Character` sort on the first character and then define the second comparison as `Integer` sort on the remaining sub-string:

```
String[] arr = {"T1", "C1", "C2", "T2", "C3", "T3", "A1", "T4", "G1", "A2", "G2", "A3", "T5",
    "C4", "C5", "T6", "A4", "T7", "T8", "C6", "T9", "A5", "T10", "G3", "A6", "A7", "A8", "C7",
    "C8", "T11", "T12", "C9", "A9", "$1", "G4", "A10", "C10", "C11", "A11", "A12", "A13",
    "A14", "T13", "T14", "C12", "T15", "C13", "C14", "G5", "G6", "C15"};
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.<String, Character>comparing(s -> s.charAt(0))
    .thenComparingInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1))));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

will print

```
[$1, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9, A10, A11, A12, A13, A14, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15, G1, G2, G3, G4, G5, G6, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You must make an own `Comparator` object for sorting in another order than default. Strings are sorted in lexicogrphic order when you do not supply an own comparator. Instead of `Collection.sort` you can use the new method of `List`.

```
myList.sort(new MyComparator());
```

The class `MyComparator` is an instance of `Comparator`:

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {
   ...
}
```

You have to implement the method `compareTo`.